# Context getFilesDir() on external call/intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

This hopefully hasn't been asked to many times (or at all!), but I am wondering about how `Context`s will work when an application is opened through it's `<intent-filter>` from another app, versus its `MAIN` `LAUNCHER` intent.

Essentially, is everything app specific, even though the app is being opened by another app. If I call getFilesDir() on the `Activity`, since it is a subclass of `Context`, will it give me my application's directory, or the other application's?

To me, I would understand it that it would open the other application's directory, but I was hoping to get a better understanding about what exactly is happening (and what I have access to) from one or some of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open an app with an Intent, you've opened the app. If app A sends an Intent to app B, app B opens and the code that executes is in app B. The Context is the context for app B.

Having said that, though, app B can access files created by app A if app A puts the files in a "public" area.

What's the use case?

Comment: Thanks! The use case is I am allowing my application to open a certain file type and respond to a certain URI extension in browsers, but I need access to my App's directory to read and write from certain files.

Comment: What do you mean by public? Not that I need to, but how would you access public files?